# Nintex Approval workflow with parallel branches

Tags: nintex-workflow

I have following scenario with nintex workflow (Nintex workflow only, no other workflow.)

I have made ab approval workflow with parallel branch which requests for approval and in parallel it checks that whether the start time for the task is less than the current time or not? If yes then it terminates the workflow.

The problem I am facing here is that both the branch runs only once (i.e when workflow starts). I want that the the left branch (checking the date condition) should run until the approval process is completed.

for example, (here I have a room reservation system, so the Task Date is the Start Date for reserving the room)

Task Date (Start Date) is 10th july 2015 3:00PM

and the workflow is started on 9th july 2015 1:00PM.

so now, the workflow branches will execute for once, after that I want that the Date-Checking branch should continue to execute until or unless any of approver has not given any response to the approval task (i.e. Neither accept Nor Reject). In this case the action will continue to work on that branch and perform the intended actions.

How can i achieve this ?

following is the workflow which i have implemented so far.

Thanks in advance and Apologies for the lengthy description. [image]

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you would like to keep logging in the history list whilst there is no ultimate answer from the Approval. i.e. keep logging until there is an answer.

My suggestion would be to use a loop action inside your IF Statement, in order to keep logging. Once the IF statement conditions are no longer met, it will step out and end the workflow.

Please let me know if I have misunderstood